# Rails 5 Beta: Put eager_load_paths config on initializer throw frozen array exception

Tags: configuration, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed commented guidelines in config/application.rb which is

```
   # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
   # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
   # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
```

But when i added `Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` in `config/initializers/eager_load.rb`.

It throws `<top (required)>': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)`

Yes it is working if i put it inside `config/application.rb`.

I want to know why is it not working on initializer and how to make it work using the convention ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead in `config/initializers/xxx.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths += [Rails.root.join('lib')]
```